# Any experience making fig liqueur?

Tags: liquor, spirits

I've successfully made a black raspberry liqueur, and am doing a similar process now with fresh figs. Has anybody done that? What have your experiences been?

Recipe:

- 1.5 cups vodka (I'm using Tito's)
- 1.5 - 2 cups fig puree

Combine figs and vodka, shake well, store in refrigerator. Shake daily, after 2-3 weeks strain well, and add simple syrup to taste.

Comment: Excuse me for asking but is there any difference or extra hardship in making fig liqueur as opposed to another type of liquer?

Answer (score 3):

Fig liqueur completed after 4 weeks.  Here are notes:

- A lot more work than I expected it would be to strain out the liquid.
  Next time I'll use a food processor instead of making the base puree
  by hand.
- It's much darker than I expected
- The taste is nice, a little tannic on the finish.
- I've successfully used it in a Collins-type cocktail - in a rocks glass, add:

  - 2 ounces fig liqueur, chilled
  - 1.5 tbsp simple syrup
  - juice of 1 lime wedge
  - sparkling water to top

Answer (score 2):

I'm using fresh picked figs from our tree. Pureed and mixed I part good quality vodka to 1 part fig puree. I also added a tablespoon of sugar to the mixture. I'm storing the Mason jars in a cool dark closet. I'll let you know how it turns out.